# How to extract text between two patterns with sed/awk

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I know this has been asked 1000 times here, but I read a lot of similar questions and still did not manage to find the right way to do this. I need to extract a number from a line that looks like this:

```
{"version":"4.9.123M","info":{"version":[2034.2],"description":""},"status":"OK"}
```

Expected output:

```
2034.2
```

This version number will not always be the same, but the rest of the line should.

I have tried working with sed but I am new to this and failed:

```
 sed -e 's/version":[\(.*\),"description/\1/'
```

output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unterminated `s' command
```

I think the issue is that there are too many special characters involved in the line and I did not write the command very well.

Comment: Why not just `jq '.info.version[0]' file`?

Comment: I did not know about this command. It is so simple and it does exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: `[` is  a special char, it must be escaped in the regex. Anyway, even if you do that your command would not work. To parse JSON, use JSON specific tools like `jq` to avoid other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the version is always enclosed in [] and no other [ or ] is present in a line ,you can try this logic

```
STR='{"version":"4.9.123M","info":{"version":[2034.2],"description":""},"status":"OK"}'
echo $STR | awk -F'[' '{print $2}' | awk -F']' '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Very seldom you need more than one `awk`

Answer (score 6):

Since it's JSON, use should use JSON aware tools for processing it. If you prefer, for example, awk, the way is to use GNU awk's JSON extension. This is a small how-to.

First download and compile appropriate versions of GNU awk, Gawkextlib and [gawk-json](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/json/json.html). That's pretty straightforward, actually, just `./configure` and `make`. Then, write some code:

```
awk '
@load "json"                                 # enable json extension
{
   lines=lines $0                            # read json file records and buffer to var lines
   if(json_fromJSON(lines,data)==1) {        # once the json is complete
       for(i in data["info"]["version"])     # that seems to be an array so all elements
           print data["info"]["version"][i]  # are outputed
       lines=""                              # once done with the first json object
   }                                         # reset the var for more lines
}' file
```

Output this time:

```
2034.2
```

**Explained a bit more:**

The JSON file structure can vary from one line to multiple lines, for example:

```
{"version":"4.9.123M","info":{"version":[2034.2],"description":""},"status":"OK"}
```

or:

```
{
  "version": "4.9.123M",
  "info": {
    "version": [
      2034.2
    ],
    "description": ""
  },
  "status": "OK"
}
```

so we need to buffer the JSON lines with `lines=lines $0` until there is a whole valid object in variable `lines`. We use the extension function `json_fromJSON()` to determine that validity in `if(json_fromJSON(lines,data)==1)`. While validated the object gets disentangled and stored to array `data`. For this particular object the structure of the array is:

```
data["version"]="4.9.123M"
data["info"]["version"][1]="2034.2"
data["info"]["description"]=""
data["status"]="OK"
```

We could examine the object and produce some output of it with this recursive array scanning function:

```
awk '
@load "json"
function scan(a,p,    q) {           # a is array, p path to it, q is qnd *
    if(isarray(a))
        for(i in a) {
            q=p (p==""?"":"->") i
            scan(a[i],q)
        }
    else
        print p ":" a
}
{
   lines=lines $0
   if(json_fromJSON(lines,data)==1)
       scan(data)                    #
}' file.json
```

Output:

```
status:OK
version:4.9.123M
info->version->1:2034.2
info->description:
```

*) quick'n dirty

Here is a brief example of how to output JSON from an array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58109715/4162356

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I was dropped on a gigaton of json and I had to make the best out of it. :D. The documentation is pretty non-existent. Trial and err mostly, but its only two functions and the json is stored to a multidimensional array. Sure beats `jq` IMHO.

Comment: Beat `jq`, consider me in then :) (since I am dummy in it :) ) Let me reach home and try some more experiments on same, thanks a TON for sharing this again :)

Comment: `jq` has its own fancy DSL, that's why we like it

Comment: @oguzismail Man, I've cried long nights with `jq`. Ended up installing MongoDB so that I don't need to use it anymore. Now I started with gawk-json. It's like bathing in honey. And milk. And awk.

Comment: @oguzismail Sorry sir, I'm not. I'm a native Finnish speaker. Which extension is that?

Comment: @oguzismail: I've seen your post quite a few times around here. If you are still looking for help, recommend posting it in Unix.SE and wait for a couple of days and raise a bounty. I've known some of the best experts over there and you might get a solution for it

Comment: I nominate @Inian for the job. ;D

Comment: @JamesBrown: lol ! I see you starting a trend now, JSON with `awk` is going to be the "the" thing for some time now

Comment: Well I'm rolling with [gawk-pgsql](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/pgsql/pgsql.html) ATM, just waiting for you, guys.

Comment: @JamesBrown: What's on 5.0 though? Apart from building it and aliasing it in my system, nvr really used it. Any good in it?

Comment: Compiled and tried it once, still using some old one I had installed with gawkextlib and extensions compiled. Don't even know the version. Found a bug the other day, though. Should check it out some day. `FPAT` and something.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yo, I explained the gawk-json usage a bit more here, if interested.

Comment: @JamesBrown, Sure thank you for letting me know buddy.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest Way**

Try grep when want to extract simple texts

```
 echo "{"version":"4.9.123M","info":{"version":[2034.2],"description":""},"status":"OK"}"| grep -o "\[.*\]" | sed -e 's/\[\|\]//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
STR='{"version":"4.9.123M","info":{"version":[2034.2],"description":""},"status":"OK"}'
echo "$STR" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'
2034.2
```