# group json output by array input value

Tags: json, jq

Input data: /tmp/h1.tabs, tab delimited:

```
INPUT   A1
Flavor  Controller
Comment Disabled
State   DiskOne
INPUT   B2
Flavor  Controller
Comment Not Applicable
State   Not Applicable
ConnectorCount  12
Alarm   Alarm Not present
INPUT   C3
Flavor  Controller
Comment Not Applicable
Media   Not Applicable
ConnectorCount  0
State   Alarm Not present
```

Desired Output:

```
{
    "A1": {
        "Comment": "Disabled",
        "Flavor": "Controller",
        "State": "DiskOne"
    },
    "B2": {
        "Alarm": "Alarm Not present",
        "Comment": "Not Applicable",
        "ConnectorCount": "12",
        "Flavor": "Controller",
        "State": "Not Applicable"
    },
    "C3": {
        "Comment": "Not Applicable",
        "ConnectorCount": "0",
        "Flavor": "Controller",
        "Media": "Not Applicable",
        "State": "Alarm Not present"
    }
}
```

Each INPUT dictionary key could also be an array instead of another dictionary.

```
{
    "A1": [
        { "Comment": "Disabled" },
        { "Flavor": "Controller" },
        { "State": "DiskOne" }
    ],
```

About as close as I am able to get is something like this:

jq -Rsn '[inputs|. / "\n"|.[] / "\t"|select(length > 0)|. as $input|(if $input[0] == "INPUT" then $input[1] else { ($input[0]): $input[1] } end)]' /tmp/h1.tabs

```
[
  "A1",
  {
    "Flavor": "Controller"
  },
  {
    "Comment": "Disabled"
  },
  {
    "State": "DiskOne"
  },
  "B2",
  {
    "Flavor": "Controller"
  },
```

I've tried expressions like if $input[0] == "INPUT" then $block = $input[1], but I am not having any luck with an assignment, so I can't use the assignment in the output.  Really what I think I need is a variable set to whatever INPUTs value is every time I pass it.  Then I can format the output as needed.  I am just missing some key magic.  I've been banging on this for a while, here is more that doesn't work...

```
# vim:ft=ansible:tabstop=8 expandtab shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
"unknown" as $block
|[
  inputs
  |. / "\n"
  |
  (
    .[]
    | select(length > 0)
    |.
  )
]
|(.[] / "\t")
|select(length > 0)
|. as $input
|
(
  if $input[0] == "INPUT" then $block = $input[1] else empty end
  |({($block): [($input[0]):($input[1])]})
) | add
```

Still learning :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` is your friend..

```
reduce (inputs / "\t") as [$k, $v] ([];
    if $k == "INPUT" then
        .[0] = $v
    else
        .[1][.[0]] += {($k): $v}
    end
) | .[1]
```

Note that you need to specify -n and -R options on the command line for this to work

Comment: i'm going to have to think about this for a while.  it worked great. i like the edit with the k,v, much cleaner.  what is the .[0], .[1]?  just arbitrary indexed variables?  I understand the assignments here...when i tried to put them 'inline' i just couldn't make it work...just the wrong place i guess.  thank you.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's what they are called. It keeps A1, B2 etc. in .[0] for reference, and builds the desired object in .[1]

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk, gawkextlib and gawk-json:

```
$ gawk '
@load "json"
BEGIN{
    FS="\t"
}
{
    if($1=="INPUT")
        tl=$2
    else
        data[tl][$1]=$2
}
END {
    print json_toJSON(data)
}' file                           # | jq '.'  # for eye-friendly formating
```

Output (`jq` assisted):

```
{
  "C3": {
    "Comment": "Not Applicable",
    "State": "Alarm Not present",
    "ConnectorCount": "0",
    "Flavor": "Controller",
    "Media": "Not Applicable"
  },
  "A1": {
    "Comment": "Disabled",
    "State": "DiskOne",
    "Flavor": "Controller"
  },
  "B2": {
    "Comment": "Not Applicable",
    "State": "Not Applicable",
    "Alarm": "Alarm Not present",
    "ConnectorCount": "12",
    "Flavor": "Controller"
  }
}
```

Comment: nice. i must admit that this type of approach is more comfortable to my programming brain.  i still haven't gotten over the learning curve for jq (yet)

Comment: @Greg I know. See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075952/how-to-extract-text-between-two-patterns-with-sed-awk/58076281#comment102547659_58076281).